# How to do a nested search based on multiple tab dependent values?

Tags: excel, vba

I have three worksheets, Accounts, JEExtracts & Detail Extracts.

[image: New Example with Data]

I would like to search based on values from Accounts WS which is unique and find all matches from JEExtracts, then based on all matching values found, take values of another cell corresponding to that row and search all instances from Detail extracts WS.

When I do that, the first iteration works. In the second iteration the searchstring loses its value. It ends in error object not defined.

```
Sub FilterAccount()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim searchRng As Range
    Dim searchRng2 As Range
    Dim LastAcc As Long
    Dim LastRowJE As Long
    Dim LastRowDE As Long
    Dim fAddress
    Dim fAddress2

    LastAcc = Sheets("Accounts").Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    LastRowJE = Sheets("JournalExtract").Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown).Row
    LastRowDE = Sheets("DetailExtract").Cells(2, 10).End(xlDown).Row

    LastAcc = LastAcc - 1
    LastRowJE = LastRowJE - 1
    LastRowDE = LastRowDE - 1

    ACRow = 2
    ACCol = 1
    JERow = 2
    JECol = 7
    DERow = 2
    DECol = 10

    Worksheets("Accounts").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Loop through cells to do the lookup based on value on a particular column of worksheet Accounts
    For Each c In Sheets("Accounts").Range(Cells(ACRow, ACCol), Cells(LastAcc, ACCol))
        'MsgBox (c.Value)

        If IsEmpty(c) = True Then Exit For       'If there is no value found in the cell then exit from the process
        If IsEmpty(c) = False Then               'If there is value found in the cell then search the same value in JournalExtract

            Worksheets("JournalExtract").Activate

            With Sheets("JournalExtract").Range(Cells(JERow, JECol), Cells(LastRowJE, JECol)) 'Using the cells looking up resource name in pivot tab
                Set searchRng = .Find(What:=c.Value) 'Find it

                If Not searchRng Is Nothing Then 'If we find a value
                    fAddress = searchRng.Address 'Set the address to compare

                    Do
                        searchRng.Offset(0, 0).Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                        Worksheets("DetailExtract").Activate

                        'Using the value from worksheet JournalExtract looking up value in DetailExtract
                        With Sheets("DetailExtract").Range(Cells(DERow, DECol), Cells(LastRowDE, DECol))

                            Set searchRng2 = .Find(What:=searchRng.Offset(0, 4)) 'Find it
                            If Not searchRng2 Is Nothing Then
                                fAddress2 = searchRng2.Address

                                Do
                                    searchRng2.Offset(0, 0).Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                                    Set searchRng2 = .FindNext(searchRng2)
                                Loop While Not searchRng2 Is Nothing And searchRng2.Address <> fAddress2

                            End If
                            Set searchRng2 = Nothing

                        End With

                        Worksheets("JournalExtract").Activate
                        Set searchRng = .FindNext(searchRng) 'Doesn't get value in 2nd iteration

                    Loop While Not searchRng Is Nothing And searchRng.Address <> fAddress 'Here error is thrown - Object value not set.

                End If

            End With

        End If
        Set searchRng = Nothing
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: A Find/FindNext pair can only be used one at a time. If you try to Find/FindNext using the value from the first Find/FindNext, the first is removed and replaced by the second. You need an alternative method of location for the nested lookup.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I tried my best but failed. I am thinking to first auto filter values in 2nd ws based on value from 1st then do a find/findnext. :(

Answer (score 0):

A Find/FindNext pair can only be used one at a time. If you try a nested Find/FindNext using the value from the first Find/FindNext, the first is removed and replaced by the second. You need an alternative method of location for the nested lookup or you can isolate each process.

This is hopefully closer to what you need but I didn't fully test it. It builds a union from the results of the first Find/FindNext pair then cycles through that union of ranges to process the second Find/FindNext pair.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterAccount()


    Dim c As Range, s As Range
    Dim searchRng As Range, foundRng As Range
    Dim searchRng2 As Range
    Dim LastAcc As Long, LastRowJE As Long, LastRowDE As Long
    Dim ACRow As Long, ACCol As Long, JERow As Long, JECol As Long, DERow As Long, DECol As Long
    Dim fAddress As String, fAddress2 As String

    LastAcc = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1
    LastRowJE = Worksheets("JournalExtract").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row - 1
    LastRowDE = Worksheets("DetailExtract").Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row - 1

    ACRow = 2
    ACCol = 1
    JERow = 2
    JECol = 7
    DERow = 2
    DECol = 10

    With Worksheets("Accounts")

        'Loop through cells to do the lookup based on value on a particular column of worksheet Accounts
        For Each c In .Range(.Cells(ACRow, ACCol), .Cells(LastAcc, ACCol))

            'If there is no value found in the cell then exit from the process
            If IsEmpty(c) Then
                Exit For
            Else

                With Worksheets("JournalExtract")

                    'Using the cells looking up resource name in pivot tab
                    With .Range(.Cells(JERow, JECol), .Cells(LastRowJE, JECol))

                        Set searchRng = .Find(What:=c.Value) 'Find it

                        'If we find a value
                        If Not searchRng Is Nothing Then
                            fAddress = searchRng.Address 'Set the address to compare
                            Set foundRng = searchRng
                            'collect all the searchRngs into a union
                            Do
                                Set foundRng = Union(foundRng, searchRng)
                                Set searchRng = .FindNext(after:=searchRng)
                            Loop While searchRng.Address <> fAddress

                            foundRng.Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

                            'now on to the second search
                            'cycle through the union
                            For Each s In foundRng

                                With Worksheets("DetailExtract")
                                    'Using the value from worksheet JournalExtract looking up value in DetailExtract
                                    With .Range(.Cells(DERow, DECol), .Cells(LastRowDE, DECol))

                                        Set searchRng2 = .Find(What:=c.Offset(0, 4)) 'Find it

                                        If Not searchRng2 Is Nothing Then

                                            fAddress2 = searchRng2.Address

                                            Do
                                                searchRng2.Offset(0, 0).Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                                                Set searchRng2 = .FindNext(searchRng2)
                                            Loop While searchRng2.Address <> fAddress2

                                        End If
                                    End With
                                End With
                            Next s
                        End If
                    End With
                End With
            End If

        Next c
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Great direction, one step closer.Thank you for you great knowledge and time. The focus is offset value search from the second tab within 3rd tab. So flow is like I need to get account from 1st tab, get the multiples accounts from the 2nd tab then get all the link ids of all accounts found from 2nd tab then find all the link ids from 3rd tab. I have uploaded another image for an example. Currently it is finding only first link id on the result set but not the next one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL to query your data. Note that I changed `Accounts` to `Account`. [Sample workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvqfUD6Rp0UCkzL1QcQLcv9aG--T).

```
Sub FindValues()

    Dim c%, sql$, conn_string$
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim wksOutput As Worksheet

    conn_string = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                  "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
                  "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0"";"

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient

    sql$ = "SELECT A.Account, J.[Link ID], DE.[Values] " & _
           "FROM ([Accounts$] AS A " & _
           "INNER JOIN [JEExtracts$] AS J " & _
                "ON A.Account = J.Account) " & _
            "INNER JOIN ['Detail Extracts$'] AS DE " & _
                "ON J.[Link ID] = DE.[Link ID];"

    rs.Open sql, conn_string, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Set wksOutput = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        wksOutput.Name = "output"
        With wksOutput
            '// Output headers
            For c = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
                .Cells(1, c + 1) = rs.Fields(c).Name
            Next
            .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "No records were found.", vbExclamation
    End If

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```